# Highcharts Automatic resizing of indicators when adding axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am storing chart data in localstorage.
Then I add them to the chart.

```
chart_obj.addAxis({
    id: element.yAxis,
    lineWidth: 1,
    lineColor: '#08F',
    offset: 0,
});

chart_obj.addSeries({
    type: element.type,
    linkedTo: ''+element.linkedTo+'',
    yAxis: element.yAxis
});
```

[image]

As a result, my height indicator is on a different indicator.
The thing is that you have to set the height and position manually there.

But, when you add an indicator from the menu of indicators, it is added normally.
Example

[image]

How does adding yAxis automatically recalculate the height?

I tried different methods from the API, read the forum - but nowhere found information on how to do it.

Comment: Maybe you can add a more concrete example of what your issue is, starting from one of the fiddles in the [docs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/technical-indicator-series). I tried myself one of the examples and I don't see any difference between the case when you add dynamically an axis-series pair https://jsfiddle.net/g74c8yh9/ vs the default static case https://jsfiddle.net/q28dk1xu/

Comment: @kikon
 Try removing top: '65%', height: '35%' and it will be like my example.
I don't know the top and height, because there can be several indicators.

Comment: Well, I think allocating the fraction of the vertical space for each series is up to you. When you add a new axis you set its height and top according to the current number of axes and then recompute the same for each the existing y axes, using [`axis.update`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update). In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwsoz560/) I implemented a simple strategy that allocates equal space to each axis, but of course you can implement a more sophisticated one using the type of the series. But I don't think there is a predefined function for that.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the series do not scale, you need to do an [update](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update) on the axes and set their top and height.

```
  chart_obj.yAxis[0].update({
    title: {
      text: 'updated'
    },
    height: '50%',
    top: '50%'
  })
  chart_obj.addSeries({
    type: 'ao',
    yAxis: 1,
    greaterBarColor: '#00cc66',
    lowerBarColor: '#FF5E5E',
    linkedTo: 'AAPL',
    showInLegend: true
  });
  chart_obj.yAxis[1].update({
    title: {
      text: 'updated'
    },
    height: '50%',
    top: '0%'
  })
},
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u3s2cjyv/